# Duplicate a GA4 Property for Training Users

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have GA4 set up with GTM. We need to train the staff on using GA4, but we do not want those users in the master property playing around. To resolve this, we thought an exact duplicate property would be the solution. When creating the duplicate property, we cannot choose the same data source as the master, only create a new one. What would be the best method of duplicating the master property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to duplicate the property would be to use another measurement id in your tracking, effectively sending the data to one more endpoint.

However, the idea to duplicate a property to teach stuff is not reasonable. There's no reason to not allow them into the main property if you keep them at read-only permissions.

Another way to duplicate a property would be re-inserting the data through a measurement protocol, first exporting it from the original property, but, again, that's an overkill.

Comment: Thanks, @BNazaruk.  I'll bring this back to the team. I appreciate your reply!